# Move different lists together in MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, list-template

I'm currently trying to move two lists together, those two lists are created on different list templates, one is an Issue Tracking list and the other is a Custom List, is it possible to move them together to a third empty list using standard functionality? I tried it using Content and Structure and was not surprised over getting a message saying that the lists aren't compatible. Any workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with powershell? You could do it with powershell.

Otherwise, you could export the data in Excel format. Join them manually. And import the data back to SharePoint.